# How can we fix the customized table ui on iphone devices?

Tags: html, css, iphone, user-interface

I have customized the bootstrap table on responsive view with the help of media query and it showing well on all browser and all android phone. but when I checked the pages on iPhone then I saw all the table view is broken.

I have used the below code for table customization.

```
@media (max-width: 479px){
.opd_table table.manage_opd tr td, .opd_table table.manage_opd tr th {
    float: left;
    width: 100%!important;
    text-align: left;
}    
.opd_table table.manage_opd tr {
    padding: 20px 0 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}    
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMGWV.png   (This is the expected result)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjGdV.jpg  (And this is the broken UI result on iPhone devices)

Comment: could u provide more detail ! cz cant with only seeing css!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should be able to achieve desired result with Bootstrap columns, have a look at:[Bootstrap columns](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp). If you are new to Bootstrap it is worth learning as it can make front end development so much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

I have already used the bootstrap table but, I customized the table is responsive view so that it looks like a list rather than a table. The list UI is showing good in android phones but the UI got broke down in iPhone.


you can check the below screenshots regarding the issue

http://i.imgur.com/j4h8A2y.png (This is the expected result)

http://i.imgur.com/Px21h93.jpg (And this is the broken UI result on iPhone devices)